# What is the pseudoinvesre of a projection matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What is the pseudoinverse of a projection matrix $P$? By projection matrix $P$, I mean that $P^2 = P$, but maybe $P^T\not = P$.

Denote the pseudoinverse of $P$ by $P^\dagger$. What actually I am looking for is to construct the orthogonal projection $PP^\dagger$ using the projection $P$.

Comment: See [this article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Construction) for common methods of computing a pseudoinverse, in particular the SVD method.

Comment: I am not sure what you are expecting. In general $P^\dagger$ is not a polynomial or primary matrix function in either $P$ or $P^T$. To find $PP^\dagger$, you must somehow find the column space of $P$. Anyway, we have $P^\dagger = P^T(PP^T)^\dagger$ and hence $PP^\dagger = (PP^T)(PP^T)^\dagger$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Is there any way to incorporate $P^2=P$ property to find a polynomial or primary matrix function in $P$ (or $P^T$) for $P^\dagger$?
I would be grateful if somebody introduce me a source.